# Loading data from realm file

Tags: java, android, realm

I like to load the integer from my json using the getter as followed, and it didn't work.  Did I do something wrong

```
 int position;

 Setting setting = new Setting();
 position = setting.getRadioPosition();
```

My realm class as followed:

```
public class Setting extends RealmObject {
  @Required
  private Integer RadioPosition;

  public Integer getRadioPosition() {
    return RadioPosition;
  }

  public void setRadioPosition(Integer radioposition) {
    RadioPosition = radioposition;
  }

}
```

My Json file as followed:

```
[
  {
"Notification": "True",
"RadioPosition": 1
   }
 ]
```

Comment: First parse JSON. Store value in Realm and then you can get it.

Comment: I did..I read the file in the realm browser and it worked..Just not sure if my getter function correct..Thanks for reply.

Comment: How are you inserting the JSON into Realm?

Comment: I just edited my answer.  You are free to commend.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "and it didn't work",empty data or something else? You may need to find that Setting object before you can use it .

Comment: My answer works in the main activity.  I put it in another activity and it didn't work.  What am I missing....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have added the following to load all data first.

RealmResults test = realm.where(Setting.class).findAll();

The following is how I insert my two json files:

```
 private void loadJsonFromStream() throws IOException {

    InputStream stream = getAssets().open("school.json");
    InputStream streamSetting = getAssets().open("setting.json");

    realm.beginTransaction();
    try {
        realm.createAllFromJson(School.class, stream);
        realm.createAllFromJson(Setting.class, streamSetting);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Remember to cancel the transaction if anything goes wrong.
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null && streamSetting != null) {
            stream.close();
            streamSetting.close();


        }
    }

}
```